# Sparse Array HackerRank Exercise

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to resolve some exercises from hacker rank, and I'm struggling with the array `map` and `filter` methods.

This function supposes to search a value from `queries` array into `strings` array and when I use the map method it returns an array with `undefined` values, and when I use the filter method it returns an empty array.

```
var strings = ['ab','ab','bca','acb']
var queries = ['ab','abc','bc']

function matchingStrings(strings, queries) {
let retArr = []
for(let n = 0; n<queries.length; n++){
       var equalelem = strings.filter(function(queries){queries[n] === [...strings]})
       retArr.push(equalelem.length);
    }
    return equalelem 
}

console.log(matchingStrings(strings, queries))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking only at your syntax, and without analyzing the algorithm, the following things should change:

- Your filter function always returns `undefined`. Any function that doesn't have an explicit `return` statement returns `undefined`. Maybe you wanted to use an arrow function expression, which doesn't require a return statement if you omit the curly braces?

  ```js
  var equalelem = strings.filter((queries) => queries[n] === [...strings])
  ```
- Inside the filter function, you seem to be comparing an element from list `queries` to a copy of list `strings`. Comparing an element of a list (in this case, a single string) to a list will never be true in your case.
- The variable `letArr` doesn't seem to serve any purpose.